# Is there any way to automate the ACL creation inside existing storage account blob?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm-template

We have Azure Storage account Genv2 enabled with Datalake Genv2 feature and would need to create blobs inside the containers as per the timely requirement and assign set of "access control lists" for a set of service principles with different level of accesses. Looking for a solution with terraform and couldnt find any helpful article on this.

Requirement is as below.

- Read the existing Storage account information ( which already have some blobs created with some accesspolicy)
- Create new blobs inside that storage account and assign set of access control for a list of service principals with different kind of access like read, write
- should be able to modify the existing access control list also inside the existing blobs.
  Any helps highly appreciated..

Comment: I think TF won't be a good match for this. Have you considered regular python (or similar) script to do that?

Comment: The Storage account is enabled with Datalake Gen v2 feature and requirement is to create and manage access control list of the blob containers inside them. I modified the question above with the same information. Will terraform will help on the above, if not, ARM can help ?

Comment: As Marcin said , blobs creation will be fine in terraform or ARM but access control can't be set using terraform even ARM . You can try using azure sdk's /powershell/cli .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Storage account is enabled with Datalake Gen v2 feature and
> requirement is to create and manage access control list of the blob
> containers inside them. I modified the question above with the same
> information. Will terraform will help on the above, if not, ARM can
> help ?

It is not possible with ***Terraform*** or ***ARM template*** to set/get *`ACL's`*. You can use ***Azure SDK's*** which are mentioned in this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#how-to-set-acls) as per your requirement.